# React / Redux component props from `connect` out of sync with store in click handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I ran into an interesting error in a React/Redux app that I unfortunately haven't been able to reproduce. From the stack, it looks like props in a Redux-connected component are somehow getting out of sync with the global store.

The basic idea is that the connected component has a click handler that only dispatches an action if the prop is set. Somehow the action got dispatched, but in a middleware for that action, the global store shows that the state for that prop is `null`.

Should that be possible in React/Redux? The only reason I can imagine is that something else changes the global store while the click event handling is enqueued or delayed. I don't know enough about React internals to know if that's reasonable.

Below is a very simplified version of the app. There are other parts of the app that would be dispatching `setExample` in response to other events, i.e. routing.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux'

// reducer

const defaultState = { example: null }

const setExample = example => ({ type: 'SET_EXAMPLE', example })

const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_EXAMPLE':
      return {
        ...state,
        example: action.example
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

// middleware

const middleware = store => next => action => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_EXAMPLE':
      if (!action.example && !store.getState().example) {
        console.log('impossible?')
      }
      break
    default:
      break
  }
  return next(action)
}

// component

const mapStateToProps = state => state
const mapDispatchToProps = { setExample }

const Component = props => {
  const onClick = () => {
    if (props.example) {
      props.setExample(null)
    }
  }

  return <div onClick={onClick}>example</div>
}

const ConnectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)

// app

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(middleware))

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedComponent />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: `store.getState().example.example`? depends on your which key this reducers lives in.

Comment: @xiaofan2406 the reducer is at the top level, in this case, not using `combineReducers`